# Need help identifying this thorny plant

Tags: identification, thorns

I need help identifying this plant. I have had it for six months now and it has done well until now, but the bottom leaves are starting to turn yellow, dropping bit by bit.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Too frequent watering, treat more like a cactus.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like *Euphorbia milii* (common name - crown of thorns). Here's a [link](https://www.rhs.org.uk/Plants/32739/Euphorbia-milii/Details).

Comment: Hi Peter, this is a good example of a link only answer. Can you expand on the care of this plant?

Comment: @kevinsky - the OP didn't ask about care, only about identification. If you want to know about care, follow the link :-)